# how to execute stored procedure in sql using join

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[SPEmployeeInformation]
@searchText nvarchar(100)
as
begin

select EmployeeInformation.LineId, FirstName, MidName, FatherName, MotherName, dob, MeritalStatus, ParmanentAddress,
DepartmentMaster.DepartmentName, DesignationMaster.Designation, EmployeeCategory.EmployeeCategory, Salary.Salary
from EmployeeInformation
inner join DepartmentMaster on EmployeeInformation.DepartmentName=DepartmentMaster.DepartmentLineId
inner join DesignationMaster on EmployeeInformation.Designation=DesignationMaster.DesignationLineId
inner join EmployeeCategory on EmployeeInformation.EmployeeCategory=EmployeeCategory.EmployeeCategoryLineId
inner join Salary on EmployeeInformation.LineId=Salary.EmployeeLineID
where FirstName+MidName+FatherName+MotherName+MeritalStatus+ParmanentAddress+
      DepartmentMaster.DepartmentName+DesignationMaster.Designation+EmployeeCategory.EmployeeCategory like '%'+@searchText+'%'
end
```

Comment: which db you are using ???

Comment: where is begin, if there is end in your sqlquery. Also what is the 'SearchText' field's value

Comment: Hi i am using sql db

Comment: why you add xamarin and c# if you have question related to db. sql which sqlserver or mysql? also need sample data to analysis. Just see added an answer, that will help you. Also what you get the error that also write.

Comment: It is very unlikely that your where statement does what you are trying to do. I would change it into `where firstname like '%' + @search + '%' or MidName like '%' + @search + '%' or ...`

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Why is the stored procedure definition identical to that in the answer left by Ripdaman?

Answer (score 0):

I just try to test with your scenario with sample data and its works. That means you doing wrong in query like column name or int datatype value etc.

Without sample data we can't do, just check the concept below.

```
declare @table table (fname varchar(200), lname varchar(200))
declare @patientName varchar(200) ='john'
insert into @table values ('doe', 'john'),('ritu', 'pawar'),('Vogue', 'jani')

select * from @table where fname+lname like '%'+@patientName+'%'
set @patientName ='ej'
select * from @table where fname+lname like '%'+@patientName+'%'
```

Output are

First query return below

```
fname   lname
doe     john
```

Second query return below

```
fname   lname
doe     john
Vogue   jani
```

Answer (score 0):

Using MS SQL

```
Create procedure [dbo].[SPEmployeeInformation]

@searchText nvarchar(100)
as
begin
select EmployeeInformation.LineId, FirstName, MidName, FatherName, MotherName, dob, MeritalStatus, ParmanentAddress,
DepartmentMaster.DepartmentName, DesignationMaster.Designation, EmployeeCategory.EmployeeCategory, Salary.Salary
from EmployeeInformation
inner join DepartmentMaster on EmployeeInformation.DepartmentName=DepartmentMaster.DepartmentLineId
inner join DesignationMaster on EmployeeInformation.Designation=DesignationMaster.DesignationLineId
inner join EmployeeCategory on EmployeeInformation.EmployeeCategory=EmployeeCategory.EmployeeCategoryLineId
inner join Salary on EmployeeInformation.LineId=Salary.EmployeeLineID
where FirstName+MidName+FatherName+MotherName+MeritalStatus+ParmanentAddress+   DepartmentMaster.DepartmentName+DesignationMaster.Designation+EmployeeCategory.EmployeeCategory like '%'+@searchText+'%'

end
```

**FOR EXECUTE YOUR SP**

```
exec [Your SP Name] 'Your Pram Value'
```

**---Example---**

```
exec SPEmployeeInformation 'your search text'
```

Happy Coding. :-)